# How to match and return text up to a question mark using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some post and I would like to use regex to extract the text up till (including) the first question mark?

I am stuck here:
title = metas.replace(/(^.*)?\?/, "$1");

Here is a sample text: 
"What is your name? my name is John"

Expected return:
What is your name?

Please help :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```js
var str="What is your name? my name is John";

var substr=str.replace(/\?.*$/,"")+ "?";
console.log(substr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the split

```
title = metas.split("?")[0] + "?";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis must include 1) everything *not* the question mark character, zero to many times `[^\?]*`, and 2) the question mark character, in order for your use of the string parameter to yield the desired results.  So this will work:

```js
title = metas.replace(/([^\?]*\?)/, "$1");
```

Comment: not working
 title = metas.replace(/([^\?]*\?)/, "$1"); return start string

Answer (score -1):

```js
startString="What is your name?test question? my name is John";
finString = startString.match(/^[^\?]*\?/)[0];
console.log(finString);
```

Comment: This is effectively a copy of my answer, only without any insight into how it works.

Comment: metas = "What is your name?test question? my name is John"; 
title = metas.replace(/([^\?]*\?)/, "$1");
console.log(title, 'title'); - its your code and you can copy/paste in console in inspect tools

Comment: and for the concept of how the code works, you can use https://regex101.com/